# Theres a Syntax error in my code and i cant find it: Java. can anyone see it?

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
package me.adam.project_2;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        
    }   
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable( ) {
        
    }   
    

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("launch")) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)); {
                sender.sendMessage("flying is disabled");
                return true;
            }
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            // /launch     /launch <number>
            if (args.length == 0) {
                // /launch
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Zoooooom!"); 
                p.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(2).setY(2)); 
                
                return true;
            
            }
            
            // /launch <number>
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Zoooooom!");
            p.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(Integer.parseInt(args[0])).setY(2)); { 
            
            return true;
        }                           
        return false;
    }
            
            
            
}
```

Comment: So if I delete the semicolon my code should work.

Answer (score 1):

The second `if` statement has a semicolon in the wrong place.

`if (!(sender instanceof Player));` <-

Answer (score 1):

you can't have a semicolon at the end of things like if statements or basically anything that uses a curly brace because having a semicolon tells the compiler that it is the end of the line and that the { after the semicolon is a new line of code